# Stolarsky array and Stolarsky representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, integer-sequences

Let $T(n,k)$ be [A035506](https://oeis.org/A035506), i.e., Stolarsky array read by antidiagonals. Here we consider that $T(n,k)=0$ for $n<1, k<1$.

Let $a(n)$ be [A200714](https://oeis.org/A200714), i.e., Stolarsky representation interpreted as binary to decimal integers.

Let $\operatorname{tr}(n)$ be [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814), i.e., the number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of $n$.

Let $b(n)$ be the sequence of positive integers such that
$$b(n)=T(b(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{\operatorname{tr}(n)+1}}\right\rfloor+1),\operatorname{tr}(n)+1), b(1)=1$$

I conjecture that $b(n)$ is a permutation of natural numbers. I also conjecture that
$$a(b(n))=n-1$$

To verify this conjecture one may use this PARI prog:

```
{Stolarsky(r, c)= tau=(1+sqrt(5))/2; a=floor(r*(1+tau)-tau/2); b=round(a*tau); if(c==1, a, if(c==2, b, for(i=1, c-2, d=a+b; a=b; b=d; ); d))} \\ from A035506
a(n) = {if (n == 1, return (0)); tau = (1 + sqrt(5))/2; mn = 0; while ((m = round(mn*tau)) < n, mn++; ); if (m == n, return (2*a(mn)+1)); mn = 0; while ((m = floor(mn*(1+tau)-tau/2)) < n, mn++; ); if (m == n, return (2*a(mn))); error("neither A nor B !!"); } \\ from A200714
b(n)=if(n==1, 1, Stolarsky(b(n\2^(valuation(n, 2) + 1) + 1), valuation(n, 2) + 1))
test(n)=a(b(n))==(n - 1)
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Is this just a restatement of the definition of A200714?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! Сould you please be a little more detailed? The definition of A200714 does not say anything about the connection with A035506, which is why the formula based on the latter (which I discovered by chance) is far from obvious to me.

Comment: The detailed definition of A200714 is given in https://oeis.org/A200648/a200648.txt and describes a bottom-up process in terms of the first row and column of A035506. The relationship between the first row and column and the table as a whole is described in A191426 (referenced from A035506). I haven't proved anything, but your $b$ looks suspiciously like a top-down description of the same process.